# Java commenting a function from interface or superclass

Tags: java, javadoc

In trying to adhere to proper Java doc commenting practices, when writing a class that either extends a base class or implements an interface, how do I provide a comment to a function that is already commented in either the interface specification or the base class? Do I simply copy and paste the comment from the base class or interface? That approach seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use [@inheritDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDGJCHC) instead of a manual copy of the comment in the interface.

From time to time I describe details of the implementation if that could be of interest to the user of the method. But if you ask me it is also ok to not write a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Never copy and paste comments. Otherwise it will be very hard to accurately update all of them simultaneously when anything is modified. Duplicating comments is probably worse than duplicating code because the compiler will not notice if anything gets inconsistent.

The comment of a method in a class should document what the method does, not what overridden methods from its base classes or from interfaces being implemented are doing, and by no means what methods in derived classes might be doing.

And what's most important: Don't comment things that don't require comments. The obvious stuff like argument types etc. will be generated automatically by Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc inherits the parent description by default if no other is specified, if you decide to override a javadoc it is because in this case the implementation/override of such method is so important/different that it *"deserves"* its own javadoc.

IFF you want to keep both, what I usually do is overwrite the javadoc by adding it to the local "element" (class/method) and then add a `@see` referencing to its parent "element"